# mmap with large alignment

Tags: linux, memory-management, mmap

I'm working on a memory management library that targets both Windows and Linux systems. On Windows, I'm currently using `VirtualAlloc2` with `MEM_ADDRESS_REQUIREMENTS` to allocate blocks of memory that are aligned to relatively large powers of two. *Is there any way to achieve the same result with `mmap`?*
I'm aware that a possible solution is to overallocate and then trim the excessive memory using `munmap`, but I'd like to avoid this since it potentially triples the number of system calls per allocation.

Comment: How large is "relatively large"? Page boundaries are already quite highly aligned with 4096 = 2^12.

Comment: The alignment is expected to be at least 2^20 bytes, 2^21 in most platforms.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Lets say 64 KiB, or anything larger than Linux's 4 KiB pages.